# How to access dispatch function from epic in redux-observables

Tags: redux-observable

I'd like to know if there's anyway to access redux's `dispatch` function from an epic in redux-observables (1.2).

```
export const epicDownloadProfile = (action$, { dispatch }) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(DOWNLOAD_INIT.getType()),
    switchMap(() =>
      from(downloadStart(dispatch)).pipe(
        map(() => DOWNLOAD_INIT()),
        catchError(err => of(DOWNLOAD_ERROR.asError(err.message)))
      )
    )
  )
```

I know this is not ideal, but I have a very complex function that makes a lot of things while downloading, so I'd need to pass `dispatch` to `downloadStart()`.
Redux-observables provides me with a `StateObservable` object as the second parameter of the epic, it does contain the state, but it does not contain the dispatch function... In the example `{ dispatch }` comes `undefined`. Is there any other way I can access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did mention this isn't ideal, but for others who might not read your question I must add a warning that doing this is suggestive that what you might be doing is an anti-pattern--but not always! Certainly if you're using some sort of third party library that you have no control over, and you need to pass it to it, that's an understandable workaround. Just don't be too tempted to called `store.dispatch()` around your Epics all the time, as it is a usually a sign you're fighting redux-observable. Of course, at the end of the day, this is just advice hehe :)

OK. So here's how you can do it:

redux-observable provides a way to inject dependencies into every epic. So when you create your epicMiddleware, you can pass a reference to the store, dispatch, or anything else.

https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/InjectingDependenciesIntoEpics.html

```
/* Where ever you create your store/middleware
*****************************************/
const middlewares = [];
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware({
  dependencies: {
    get store() { // or getStore() if you want
      return store;
    }
  }
});

middlewares.push(applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware));

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(...middlewares)
);

epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);

/* Where ever this epic is
*************************/
const epicDownloadProfile = (action$, state$, { store }) =>
  action$.pipe(                  dependencies ----^
    ofType(DOWNLOAD_INIT.getType()),
    switchMap(() =>
      from(downloadStart(store.dispatch)).pipe(
        map(() => DOWNLOAD_INIT()),
        catchError((err) => of(DOWNLOAD_ERROR.asError(err.message)))
      )
    )
  );
```

There are other approaches too, such as exporting your store from the module, importing it inside your epic modules. But that might not be good if you need to don't want your store to be a singleton, doing SSR, etc.

Here's another approach, if you prefer it, since you should always start the root epic *after* the store has been created anyway.

```
// Manually inject it yourself by wrapping the "root epic"
// with another function, which is basically an epic which
// defers to your root epic.
epicMiddleware.run((action$, state$) => {
  return rootEpic(action$, state$, { store });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that's nice to know, but I use  `createEpicMiddleware` before defining the store. Like this:

https://gist.github.com/matiasmm/3a8b64514d2db28a6d385f6da371d1f8


Is there a way to improve this so that I can have the store inside the epic?

Comment: @Matias ah yes, I edited my original solution (using a getter) and added another one as well.